# How to get typography details from jpg file?

Tags: css

I’ve received a jpg file and need to develop website based on it.

Is there a way to get typography details from this jpg file ? I need to know dimensions, font etc.

I tried importing jpg file into the figma but it doesn’t reveal all the details.

Please clarify how to proceed in this scenario ?

Comment: A jpg is just a bitmap image format, all it will usually contain is pixel data. The solution here is talk to whoever is asking you to develop the site.

Comment: Next to impossible. The jpeg file may have been scaled and is a bitmap format whereas virtually every font is defined in terms of vector graphics. In case this approach works due to fortunate circumstances, it is most likely not worth the trouble.

Comment: Have you tried talking to whoever wants you to create the website? They might share details with you. Otherwise just use a look-alike font since they didn't specify.

Comment: I'm trying to solve challenges from frontendmentor website and without pro feature, they won't provide details. Thus I was trying to find out alternatives